# Different intervals ValueAxis with JFreechart

Tags: jfreechart

I am trying to do a ValueAxis with different intervals. I mean, for example, I want to do a jfrechart with a valueAxis that I can see only the number 1,5,7. I have tried that with the next code but I get a valueAxis with a one fix interval.

```
    CategoryPlot categoryplot = (CategoryPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
    ValueAxis valueaxis = categoryplot.getRangeAxis();

    TickUnits units = new TickUnits();
    units.add(new NumberTickUnit(1));
    units.add(new NumberTickUnit(5));
    units.add(new NumberTickUnit(7));
   valueaxis.setStandardTickUnits(units);
```

Does anyone know how I have to do?. Thanks.

Comment: Why the discontinuity? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Comment: I want to show somes points that are important in my cotext program.